# Using 2 separate databases in Rspec for testing libary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have my Rails5 app with plenty of specs and these are running against postgres since my production/development is also postgres.

I developed some libary that lays in app/lib and definitely need specs
These specs require some narrowed down models that also need a database. Since I don't want to maintain migrations for in my postgres just for specs I thought its good to run these on sqlite3 since its generic models.

So after plenty of forth and back I am stuck.

I have the typical `spec_helper.rb` nothing spectecular and decides to go for

### `sqlite_spec_helper.rb`:

```
require './spec/support/reference_app/app'
```

### `support/reference_app/app`

```
require 'active_record/railtie'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'responders'
require './spec/support/reference_app/configure_active_record'

class Application < Rails::Application
  config.eager_load = false
  config.secret_key_base = 'supersecret'
end

class ApplicationController < ::ActionController::API
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  respond_to :json
end

Application.initialize!

require 'rspec/rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true
end
```

### `spec/support/reference_app/configure_active_record`

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: ':memory:'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  self.verbose = false

  create_table :generic_table do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :type
  end
end
```

So my usual specs have `require 'spec_helper` on top and the libary spec has `require 'sqlite_spec_helper'`. So my though would be that the libary spec then uses the sqlite connection that is loaded before.

When I run the test that is supposed to use the sqlite db I run into

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedTable ...
```

Which means that it still goes for the pg connection. Any helpful tips or information?

Comment: Whats in your `.rspec` file? It is a way of configuring what happens before the specs run.

Comment: Perhaps call `require './spec/support/reference_app/configure_active_record'` after you do `Application.initialize!` Perhaps it is overriding your ActiveRecord configuration with config/database.yml info

Comment: @ DickieBoy`.rspec` file just has to -`-color` option to avoid loading spec_helper into each test. 
@Tyrone Wilson Good tip. This at least brought me a step closer. If I run my 2 specs one of the libary and one of the postgres stack they both work fine on their own. But when I run the whole rspec suite then it fails since it all seems to run against the sqlite db. So obiously they fail. So I guess rspec is eager load everything and this ultimately that one of the dbs is the last one defined and overwrites the other.

Comment: @daniel, apart from wondering why you need to do this, personally I'd just create another environment by cloning environments/test.rb and make it libtest or something. But without knowing the full context it's difficult to comment on the best way forward for you. I do suspect that running separate tests is unnecessary. And if you want the ability to run one or the other then just tag them and run with filters.

Comment: @Tyrone the reason is that the libary I wrote need dummy models  that need a database to spec it. I dont want to use existing rails app models since they can undergo changes and are way more complex. And dummy models just with the basic dsl are easier to overview. It also make it easier to reuse the lib in other projects without rewriting the whole specs for it. It would make sense to pack it in a gem itself and spec it there but somehow I got into the idea to just have it all run with my `rspec` since its situated in `app/lib`. Also there is the plus of not touching travis, coverage...

Comment: It does sound like you should be creating a gem in that case. It also sounds like your models are "too fat". i.e. you should be using models for database related stuff only and then composing other functionality which you can test separately. https://medium.com/@tyrone.wilson/structuring-rails-modules-8dc85ef6bc74 This is my take on the subject and it has typically served me well.

Comment: Yeah was just hoping that I could get it running like this. And sure the models are pretty slim and utilize libaries and concerns to but for this dsl its nice to have a simple dummy data model also as sort of documentation. Tried it with rspec filtering with tags unfortunately the spec has to be loaded anyways to find the filter and this also requires the sqlite_spec_helper which in the end overwrites the db settings for all other specs. Guess gem it is then unless there is some input til tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my initial Question. Although keep in mind that a better way would be to extract the library to a gem and spec it there accordingly as @Tyrone suggested. Putting this into `spec_helper`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :library) do |example|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: 'sqlite3',
      database: ':memory:'
    )

    ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
      self.verbose = false

      create_table :abstract_dummies do |t|
        t.string  :type
        t.text   :meta_data
      end

      create_table :generic_table do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.string :type
      end

      create_table :users do |t|
      end
    end
  end

  config.after(:each, :library) do |example|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
  end
end
```

And `:library` to your example like

```
describe LibraryClass::Foo::Bar, :library do
end
```

This will then use the sqlite3 connection for each example and sets it back to the default `:test` in your `database.yml` This way it doesn't not affect the exsting rails stack specs.